# Regular Expression to extract a number from inside a custom string

Tags: regex

I'm learning Regular Expressions.

I'm trying to find the best way of writing an expression that extracts a number from within the parenthesis that follows the character R" so:

**Example 1:**

```
String("257*5.6+48.9/2*R(64)")
```

*reg ex would return the numeric value inside R() in this case 64.*

**Example 2:**

```
String("sin(45)*55 + X^2+R(-64.525)")
```

*reg ex would return the numeric value inside R() in this case -64.525*

**My expression so far is:**

```
/R\(\-?\d+\.?\d+\)/g
```

which returns R(number) taking into account possible decimal places and negative values.

Is there a better regular expression to match(return) only the number from inside the parenthesis that follows the character R?

Many thanks in advance for advice / help.

D

Comment: what language are yo using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using ActionScript 3.

Comment: ...extracted from Adobe's website:
"ActionScript 3.0 implements regular expressions as defined in the ECMAScript edition 3 language specification (ECMA-262)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a regex engine other than JavaScript, you can use [positive lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(?<=R\()-?\d+\.?\d*(?=\))/g
```

Comment: i think you made a mistake by putting `\.?\d*` in your regex instead of `(?:\.\d+)?` , i'll delete my answer because it's most similar to your's except the one i mentioned.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: You're right, this was just a quick and dirty fix in order not to prevent matches of single-digit integers. But who knows which number formats are valid (`.1` and `2.` might all be valid, so neither of our regexes might be the ultimate solution)...

Answer (score 2):

Get the matched group from index 1

```
R\((-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/lX9nJ9/2)

---

Use surrounding parenthesis as well for getting the desired output:

```
R\(([^\)]*)
```

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lX9nJ9/3)

Pattern explanation:

```
  R                        'R'
  \(                       '('
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    [^\)]*                   any character except: '\)' (0 or more times)
  )                        end of \1
```

---

Try [Positive Look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not if supported by the language:

```
(?<=R\()[^\)]*
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/lX9nJ9/7)

Comment: Hi Braj, in AS3 your second suggestion works (?<=R\()[^\)]*. For testing RegEx that works in AS3 I've found http://www.regexr.com/ to be more compatible. I don't know enough about RegEx to comment why.

Answer (score 0):

```
R\((\S+?)\)
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dK1xR4/11

Comment: I couldn't get this to return only the number in AS3 although it clearly works in test sites.

Comment: @user2190690 try R\((.*?)\)